# Repair Windows 8 Bootloader within Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, grub, bootloader

I was trying to boot Ubuntu from the Windows bootloader using EasyBCD, but it ended up removing Windows from the menu.
I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu and now I have Grub with Windows 8 as an option.
When I select it, it goes into the Windows 8 Bootloader which still only has Ubuntu as an option.

What can I do to be able to boot back into Windows 8 again?

Comment: boot from a Win8 DVD and select automatic repair. It rebuilds the BCD.